# Redux action refuse to work with a function but work inline

Tags: javascript, redux, action, dispatch

I'm new to Redux and JavaScript and came across this now,

The line `dispatch({type: 'REQUEST_START'});` is working but when I write like this:

`dispatch(requestStart);`

Then no action are fired!

Any idea? This is working in another app so It's something I have missed

I have this code:

```
import { booksActionTypes } from './books.types';

export const requestStart = () => ({
    type: booksActionTypes.REQUEST_START,
});

export const requestSuccess = books => ({
    type: booksActionTypes.REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    payload: books,
});

export const requestFailure = errMsg => ({
    type: booksActionTypes.REQUEST_FAILURE,
    payload: errMsg,
});


export const actionCreators = {
    // "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51374", http://erikswed.ddns.net:8965/api/BooksXml/getbooks/fromall/?title=dep&author=&genre=&price=
    // "sslPort": 44378
    requestBooks: (book) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({type: 'REQUEST_START'});
      var queryString = Object.keys(book)
        .map((key) => {
          return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(book[key]);
        })
        .join("&");
      var url = "http://erikswed.ddns.net:8965/api/BooksXml/getbooks/fromall/?" + queryString;
  
      console.log(`url: `, url);
      await fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((booksList) => {
          dispatch(requestSuccess, booksList);
        })
        .catch((rejected) => {
          console.log(rejected);
          dispatch(requestFailure, rejected);
        });
  
      // const response = await fetch(url);
      // const booksList = await response.json();
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

`requestStart` is a function (that returns an object), therefore you need to invoke it - `dispatch(requestStart())`

or make it an object, which you don't need to *invoke*

```
export const requestStart = {
    type: booksActionTypes.REQUEST_START,
};
...
dispatch(requestStart)
```

when you use a function, usually called an action creator, its useful for passing args for them to be added to the action (the object).  Its probably best to keep the function, but just invoke it so you have consistency across your actions/action creators

Comment: Thanks, dear god LOL